# Knockoutjs about foreach child parent

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc, knockout-sortable

I have a model that contains 2 arrays of type and name address and so on as follows:

```
  var model = [{"bstype":1},{"bstype":2},{"bstype":3},{"bstype":4}],
  [{"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}, 
  [{"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  [{"bstype":3, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  {"bstype":2 ,"name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}];
  [{"bstype":2, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  [{"bstype":4, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}];
```

What i want it to do is to create a list of:

something like

```
   I am not sure about this part how to implement it that is why it was gibberish.
   bstype":1 will have a view of following
     [{"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}, 
     [{"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
   bstype"2: will have a view of following
     {"bstype":2 ,"name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}];
     [{"bstype":2, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
   bstype":3 has only one
     [{"bstype":3, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
```

and so on so forth.

I am using knockout I have checked the site it only discusses about foreach but not how to access the child elements.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: The syntax in your example doesn't make sense... you've defined a list, and then a bunch of stuff after it. Can you fix this so we can more clearly see what you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I separated them to two var items first one contained the first array second the second array. Once done I used the first array to loop 4 times based on bstype. and then used the $.root.secondarray to loop through the second item.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A helper method to combine two arrays as you've done by the same key:

```
var model = [{"bstype":1},{"bstype":2},{"bstype":3},{"bstype":4}];

var modelChildren = [{"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}, 
  {"bstype":1, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  {"bstype":3, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  {"bstype":2 ,"name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  {"bstype":2, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"},
  {"bstype":4, "name":"John","Address":"Sample address"}];
```

This method will give you a new array "grouped by" the matching bstype:

```
   var result = model.map(function(elem)
          {
              return { 
                  bstype: elem.bstype,
                  children: modelChildren.filter(function(childElem) { 
                      return childElem.bstype == elem.bstype;
                  })
              };
          });
```

Comment: This is a great idea however what do I need something for mapping like use of knockout mapping plug in?

Comment: You could KO-bind directly to the plain Javascript object created by the above method, but are you wanting to convert all of the values recursively into observables so they will register changes made later to them?  If that's the case, you're right that the Knockout Mappings plugin will give you exactly what you need.  In the case of the above, (ko.mappings.fromJS(result)) will give you an observable version of "result" with everything composed underneath it converted to observables all the way down.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanna do. I want the element of my model to be observables as well.